# Ubuntu Macro/AutoClicker

Tags: mouse, automation

I'm planning to change to ubuntu, since i have it on my laptop (20.04), but there are some stuff that are holding me back, i have Razer Synapse installed on my computer, and i have configured it, so when i hold Mouse 5 its switches to Razer Hypershift and then when i click Mouse 1 or Mouse 2 it does it with Razer Turbo

Razer Hypershift
[image: Razer Hypershift]

And i want to know how to do it on linux, ive took a look on Piper but they dont support it, i also have tried openrazer but only was able to change DPI, also saw AutoKey but was only for keyboard. Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: I did not understand exactly what Hypershift does. Could you please elaborate it a bit further? Some tools I think could help you are `xbindkeys` (bind command events mouse buttons with `b:10` (e.g., for button #10)) combined with a shell script or a `xnee` macro.

Comment: Hypershift its like profiles for the mouse, so when its activated its switches to another profile that i can set the mouse keys to anything i want, so for example if i want to use a macro on Mouse1 but still use it normally, i can set it on Hypershift profile